# react-navigation push to the same screen with some different params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

At my app ,HomeScreen(A) has a FlatList with 10 items ,when press a item to push to the same screen(HomeScreen), just call the screen B, with different data ,the FlatList in the B has 5 items, but there is a question. when you click the blank at B, it will just like you press the item at the same position at A,and it will push to a new screen,.Do you have this question? please help me ,Thanks

Comment: you navigate instead of push.

Comment: Thanks fro your comment, but how to go back to the previos screen?

Comment: navigate to the same screen ,sometimes won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this question, just use the hook

```
useIsFocused
```

to judge the HomeScreen is focused or not